# SQL Server Performances Issue

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, hardware, windows-server-2008-r2

I am running 7 XML Parsers (grabbing data from 3rd party websites) on my server.

When I am running each XML Parser separately, it takes around 1 minute to go thru 15MB XML (which is pretty huge).

When I running all the 7 together, it takes around 10 minutes each to finish running.

Each XML is adding a lot of information to the DB, and running around 50,000 queries.

The server I am running my parsers on is:

- Server type: Hp Dl180 g6
- Processor type: Intel Xeon E5504
- Processor speed: 2000 Mhz
- Number of CPU's: 2
- Number of cores: 4
- RAM: 16 GB

Running SQL Server Web Edition on 2 CPU's

The problem comes when all the parsers run parallel, the SQL Server's CPU goes to 100%.

And the really big issue, is that I need to have around 50 XML Parsers in the future :(

What do you advice guys? should I upgrade the XML server maybe? or the server itself?

Maybe the SQL Server is running on 1 CPU and not on 2 CPU's? how can I check that?

Any advice would help...

Comment: Try run less parsers together. If you have 4 cores, run 4 or 3 parses in one time.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. i had 600,000 lines of XML which didn't finish processing even after an hour.
What worked for me was to break the XML into smaller chunks and insert the chunks to a temp table (my XML described TV shoes so i broke it to 200 different channels) and now it takes 1 minute for the entire XML

Comment: Thats what I did! I am parsing XML of soccer matches schedules, so now I am parsing them with small chunks (each match separately), and it does work faster, but when all run together, the CPU is so high.. and I think its just bad... any other idea maybe?

Comment: I tried to solve this with our DBA but with no luck. I guess the XML engine is problematic with big XML. I am staying with the temp table. it works good for me

Answer (score 0):

Even though the CPU is at 100%, I think your bottleneck here is I/O. Specially because you said that you have several process reading and writing data to the disk at the same time. Can you check the I/O on your server?

If the processes are hitting different tables there may be somethings you can do, like using Filegroups to split your DB into different HD.

If they are hitting the same tables, you probably have a blocking issue where parser A tries to read data to the same table parser B is writing. I would recommend, JUST TO TEST and find out if this is really the problem, running your process with isolation level read uncommited. If it runs fine, you'll know what the issue was.

Comment: Hi Diego, thanks for the comment! can you explain more what exactly should I do? I didnt 100% understood.

The parsers are reading the XML once to the memory and running in a loop on all elemetns, so basically, nothing (besides the DB itself) is saved on the disk.

And just like you said, I am just dealing with 3 tables (all the parsers).

Comment: but you said "Each XML is adding a lot of information to the DB, and running around 50,000 queries." I understood you were running several inserts and selects to your DB, and since you have more than one process doing it, they are probably fighting for the resources.
Anyway, my suggestion was to add "set transaction isolation level read uncommitted" on your parser so it wont cause blocking so we can see if this is the real issue

Comment: Can you refer me to how should I do it? I am not a DBA as you could estimate :)

Comment: you need to add "set transaction isolation level read uncommitted" before your SQL code, so if the parser calls a procedure, just do it in the beggining of the code. But you have to do it every where you hit the database, selects or inserts.

Comment: I've done this change, it helped a bit, but not dramatically. Maybe a stronger SQL Server would help? Standard edition and not the Web edition?

Comment: Better server would help, course!
Just remember that with this change are reading uncommited data. It may break your process